# What is the correct way to bind a Skeleton to a SkinnedMesh in three.js?

Tags: three.js

So I have set of inverse bone matrices, and a set of bones I want to bind to a skinned mesh, along with a world transform matrix for the whole mesh. I can apply the bones correctly, but not the mesh transformation for the whole mesh (and likewise, if I apply the mesh transformation then the skinning transforms are incorrect)

This code will have correct skinning (I can debug render the bones, and rotate arbritary bones and the transforms are correct):

```
skeleton = new THREE.Skeleton( bones , boneInvMtx);
skeleton.pose();
mesh.bind( skeleton);
```

But the mesh transform doesn't work, when I apply my matrix to the SkinnedMesh object it has no effect. Forcing a world matrix update has no effect (and If I disable skinning in the material the transform is applied fine).

```
mesh.applyMatrix(meshXform)
```

If instead I pass the meshXform into the bind function, the transform is applied but now all the bone transforms are incorrect (applying a rotation causes a rotation around the world axis, not the joint axis, and no transformations are applied from the scene parent)

```
mesh.bind( skeleton, meshXform );
```

Any thoughts on the correct way to setup a mesh like this?

I set up the bones (arranged in a hierarchy) and a set of bone matrices like this (and I can verify the hierachy and the matrices are correct):

```
const bones = [];
const boneInvMtx = [];

for(i=0;i<numBones;i++)
    bones.push(new Bone());
    boneInvMtx.push(boneData[i].invMtx);
};
for(i=0;i<numBones;i++)
    bones[boneData[i].parent].add(bone[i]);
```

I create the geometry, material, and mesh like this (adding the bones to the geometry has no effect):

```
var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geom.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute( indBuffer, 1 ));
geom.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( posBuffer, 3 ) );
geom.addAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normBuffer, 3) );
geom.addAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvBuffer, 2 ) );
geom.addAttribute( 'skinWeight', new THREE.BufferAttribute( weightsBuffer, 4 ) );
geom.addAttribute( 'skinIndex', new THREE.BufferAttribute( boneIndBuffer, 4 ) );

const nodeMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { skinning:true} );
const mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geom, nodeMaterial );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh worked it out. You need to add the root bone to the mesh:

```
mesh.add(bones[0])
```

Comment: I know it is an old question.. but please may you elaborate more on why it works? in my test, doing as you suggest with a mesh and a skeleton helper updates the helper but not the mesh. and at a first glance sounds weird to add the bone as the whole skeleton was already bind. appreciate your comments. thks